# Facebook Social Button plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, social-networking

So I've been trying for some time to integrate this plugin provided by facebook at [Facebook-Social-Button-Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

and there it has even mentioned to copy/paste the given code, to see it in action :-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Website Title</title>
<!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your share button code -->
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**But it isn't showing anything in the page**
So am I missing something or is there any problem with this plugin, like I need to get it in a running web server and not in some localhost or it has to do with creating app in fb to use this feature, since none of this mentioned in their documentation.

---

And yeah I've tried putting correct meta properties and data-href in accordance to my localhost as I am building my web app in laravel framework.

Comment: any errors/warnings/infos in the browser console? localhost is fine, as long you don´t just open the html file in the browser without a server. but you should definitely create an app for it and include the app id in the js sdk code.

Comment: Ah, yes I never thought to check the console, since I was trusting FB API, but here's the issue, `GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` 
Though I wonder why, since I copy pasted their code without adding anything just to test.

Comment: The code is intended to be used on website that you call via `http://` or `https://` in your browser. A URL starting with `//` is protocol-relative, meaning it is completed using the same protocol that was used to request the page itself. That of course can’t work if you test your page via the local file system, instead of “properly” via a (local) web server.

Comment: Yeah actually I used it in live server too, but there was this problem `VM114 sdk.js:99 Uncaught Error: invalid version specified` and the solution is to get a different url for fb jdk with app and app ID mentioned in it, which is nowhere mentioned in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried the code and I get the error
`VM114 sdk.js:99 Uncaught Error: invalid version specified`
seems to be an error on their code or the example wasn't meant to be copy and pasted, however if you generate the code by clicking the get code button you will get a slightly different code that contains a different url with your appID and version looks something like this:

```
 connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=XXXXXXXXXX
```

that seems to work

Comment: Yeah, I had to use APP and APP ID in order to connect to facebook, but there is nothing written about that in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start a server on localhost or put it on a live server, or it will not work. The error message mentioned in the comments tells me that you tried to just open the HTML file directly.

You can also add https to the URL (https://connect.facebook.net...), but i would rather use a server on localhost. Also, the page MUST be available in public to make the OG Tags work. Facebook needs to be able to parse the data from their servers.

Btw, you should always use an App and add the App ID - use the code from the generator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: well...i am not sure what you do, but try it on a real server. read my edits, you need a real one anyway to make the og tags work.

Comment: something is definitely wrong with your server. it should just add the protocol, not "localhost" too: //connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js will automatically become https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

Comment: I wonder what's wrong, since i tried again and this time I am getting this error `sdk.js:99 Uncaught Error: invalid version specified`.

Comment: Oh okay it worked, the problem is that it needs to receive an APP ID and APP NAME which i got from get code and copy pasted in this example, but that's poor documentation they never mentioned anything about it!

Comment: well, app id is not neccessary, but it´s a good idea to have it. you should definitely add the api version though. always use the code from the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but i was struggling for hours to make a custom share link with no text just a custom image and the way that worked was:

- Taking the code from the button configurator from the link listed in the post on top "Facebook-Social-Button-Plugin"
- Adding the adjusted meta data showed below the configurator
- Rewriting the css

  `.fb-share-button, .fb_iframe_widget, #facebook {
      width: 70px !important;
      height: 70px !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: -46px !important;
      background: url(../img/like.png) no-repeat !important;
      background-size: contain !important;
  }

  .fb-share-button a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }

  .fb_iframe_widget span {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      width: 70px  !important;
      height: 70px  !important;
      text-align: justify;
  }

  .fb_iframe_widget iframe {
      position: absolute;
      width: 70px  !important;
      height: 70px !important;
  }

  .fb_iframe_widget iframe #facebook .inlineBlock {
      display: inline-block;
      zoom: 1;
      background: transparent !important;
      width: 70px !important;
      height: 70px !important;
  }

  ._2tga._3e2a {
      background: transparent !important;
      color: transparent !important;
      border-radius: 35px !important;
      width: 70px !important;
      height: 70px !important;
  }

  path[Attributes Style] {
        fill: transparent !important;
  }`
- Removing the "Share" in anchor (my layout was just a picture) or changing it
- Optional: if you want to display quoted text just add it on the end of the link like this (you can also change the title and description of the link like that)

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&src=sdkpreparse&quote=here+comes+the+quote

-Optional 2: if you want to share/open the link as a popup, add window.open onclick function to the anchor

Full div example with popup and quote without text :

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="popup" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse&quote=here+comes+the+quote','popup','width=600,height=500'); return false;" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse&quote=here+comes+the+quote"></a></div>
```

(the data-size and data-layout are not important cause the css is overwritten)

I'm sure there are better ways of doing it but i couldn't find any! I tried with the FB.ui but it didn't work.

I hope this helps somebody!

[Button looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF81q.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you add you data and click "Get Code" button they give this markup back

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Try this way.

Comment: I've already tried this code, and yes it works, But i want to implement meta tags so as to customize my share template.